# then() getting called before promise is resolved

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

In my React App I'm making I'm trying to get the first Season, the default season, in the database to be returned, if there isn't a season selected. It should then return all the sessions connected to that seasion and add them to the state.

For some reason `defaultSeason` isn't resolving before the `then()` function fires.

```js
const getDefaultSeason = (uid) => 
{
    return database.ref(`subs-tracker/users/${uid}/seasons/`)
    .orderByChild('seasonName').limitToFirst(1).once('value')
    .then((snapshot) =>
    {
        let season;
        snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) =>
        {
            season = childSnapshot.key;
        })

        return season;
    });
};

export const startSetSessions = ( seasonUuid ) =>
{
    if ( seasonUuid ) 
    {
        return ( dispatch, getState ) =>
        {
            const uid = getState().auth.uid;
            return database.ref(`subs-tracker/users/${uid}/sessions/${seasonUuid}`)
                .once('value')
                .then((snapshot) =>
                {
                    const sessions = [];

                    snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) =>
                    {
                        sessions.push(
                        {
                            id: childSnapshot.key,
                            ...childSnapshot.val()
                        });
                    });

                    sessions.forEach((session) =>
                    {
                        const index = sessions.findIndex( (currentSession) =>
                        {
                            return session.id === currentSession.id;
                        });

                        sessions[index] = {...session, recordType: 'SESSION'}
                    })

                    dispatch(setSessions( sessions ));
                });
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return ( dispatch, getState ) =>
        {
            const uid = getState().auth.uid;

            const sessions = [];

            const defaultSeason = getDefaultSeason(uid);

            defaultSeason // this is not resolving first
            .then(database.ref(`subs-tracker/users/${uid}/sessions/${defaultSeason}`)
            .once('value')
            .then((snapshot) =>
            {
                snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) =>
                {
                    sessions.push(
                    {
                        id: childSnapshot.key,
                        ...childSnapshot.val()
                    });
                });

                sessions.forEach((session) =>
                {
                    const index = sessions.findIndex( (currentSession) =>
                    {
                        return session.id === currentSession.id;
                    });

                    sessions[index] = {...session, recordType: 'SESSION'}
                })

                dispatch(setSessions( sessions ));
            }));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you expect ``.then(database.ref(`subs-tracker/users/${uid}/sessions/${defaultSeason}`)`` to do. `.then()` expects a callback function as its argument

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been addressed above. Except replacing the `defaultSeason` into `getDefaultSeason(uid)` as the answer above.

```
 getDefaultSeason(uid)
.then(database.ref(`subs-tracker/users/${uid}/sessions/${defaultSeason}`)
.once('value')
```

You can also put an `await` in your code such that

```
const defaultSeason = await getDefaultSeason(uid) // This should resolve the issue with minimum change of source code
```

Comment: I don't see how this would work at as there's no value for defaultSeason for the path. Unfortunately I can't use `async` or `await` as I get the error 'Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.'